# VS Code IntelliSense is not showing some classes in for auto-import in my TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have a project with an entrypoint index.ts in the base folder and all the files located in src (build in dist).

When I want autocomplete or quick fix to import an existing class , it don't show up for all the classes (some old one are there but not the newer I write).
If I do the same things on a file located in ./src it work but not in the ./index.ts

I have a `FollowUserUseCase` class in ./src/application/usecase/

I also have a `Followee` class in ./src/domain/

If I try to type "follow" then ctrl-space in ./index.ts , it don't show up anything.

If I import manually FollowUserUseCase in index.ts, I can of course use the FollowUserUseCase class and methods and I can also create a new object of type Followee with auto import this time.

I assume its related to the path of the file I edit but how do I define that ?

My tsconfig.json :

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "CommonJS" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["./index.ts"]
}
```

I build my project with :

"build": "tsc --build && esbuild index.ts --bundle --platform=node --format=cjs --outfile=dist/index.js"

I tried restarting vscode and ts server of course

Is this a settings in my tsconfig.ts or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults for [`files`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files) is `false`, for [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) is `[]` if `files` is specified; `**/*` otherwise, and for [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) is node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages, and [outDir](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir). If you specify `include`, then everything that you don't specify in there won't be included for IntelliSense. You can either delete your `include` property and take the default of `**/*`, or specify something like `["index.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]`

Comment: thanks for the clear info about the different options.

Answer (score 0):

okay nevermind, I removed the include setting in tsconfig and it worked fine.
But I don't really understand why.